# Simplifying code in a class hierarchy

Tags: java, class, static

At the top of my class hierarchy is the class `Mammal`.  **Each instance of `Mammal` is required to statically initialize itself.** (The example is silly, I know.  If you are curious, I am using Android fragments and I cannot override their constructors)

For example:

```
public abstract class Mammal{
    private static initialize(int a, String b, ...){
        ...
    }  
}

public class Dog extends Mammal{
    public static Dog newInstance(int a, String b, ...){
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        initialize(a, b, ...);
    }
}

public class Cat extends Mammal{
    public static Cat newInstance(int a, String b, ...){
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        initialize(a, b, ...);
        return cat;
    }
}
```

The classes could continue indefinitely.  I have looked into [calling a subclass constructor from a superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891824/call-subclass-constructor-from-abstract-class-in-java) but I cannot figure out how to apply it to a static context.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do your initialize do that cannot be done in a consructor?

Comment: See [this for why I cannot override the constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Comment: do the initialize need to be static or only the newInstance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialize method should have a the a Mammal as parameter to initialize it's data from the other parameters:

```
  private static initialize(Mammal mammal, int a, String b, ...){
     mammal.setA(a)
     // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle Java Docs

> If a subclass defines a static method with the same signature as a
>   static method in the superclass, then the method in the subclass
>   hides the one in the superclass.

It is better explained at here [Overriding vs Hiding Java - Confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594052/overriding-vs-hiding-java-confused)

To access child class's method you need to call the method with reference of the subclass

```
Mamal mamal = new Dog();
mamal.initialize(..) // method of super class
((Dog)mamal).initialize(...)// method of class dog
```